# Use keyboard shortcut for Javascript bookmarklets in IE 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, keyboard-shortcuts, bookmarklet

is it possible to create a keyboard shortcut for javascript bookmarklets in IE 8

i opened up a bookmark properties assigned shortcutkey ctrl+alt+1 when i use it it gives me error 
"internet explorer Cannot download
Unspecified error"

and my bookmark url is :

```
javascript:(function(){alert("Hello");})();
```

Comment: I think IE8 does not work with shortcuts of bookmarklets.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I have found thus far is to save it as a favorite to the main Favorites menu. Then simply access it by pressing Alt+A > Up arrow > Enter

Yes, it means three steps, but it's still faster than reaching for the mouse.